# why the custom dimention on google analytics only showing 77% of total sessions?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have made two custom dimensions in Google analytics (Author & Category (I put the scope type on SESSION)). But after collecting data I can see that the result is based on 77% of total sessions. Why is that? How can I change that to 100%?
Is it related to the scope type I have chosen? should it be Hit? what else should I check? Is it related to the Tag Manager account?

I am totally lost on it, any help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPzUO.png)

my main problem is when I want to see the session of landing pages I see different sessions with and without a custom dimension.

This is how I see my landing pages: which shows 100% of the session
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnet9.png)

And here is when I add a custom dimension to the landing pages: which shows a lower number of sessions and I believe that is because of 77% of sessions for custom dimension.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD3dH.png)

So, why there are differences between sessions when I add a custom dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the scope will not help.

This likely means that you only have this data for 77% of sessions. So there are 23% of sessions that never get this custom dimension populated. You should look into your logic. Maybe you don't populate it on every page? Maybe the data you use to populate it is not available everywhere?

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. This data logically should be on every pages. because each article we publish has an author and category tag. But what should i check to make sure? Our website?

Comment: A homepage would not have it. Some static pages would not have it. Categories would not have it. So definitely not every page. There are many ways to see what pages don't have it. One of them would be adding a catch-all logic to your custom dimension to give it "Not Set" value when your variables are empty. Then look what page urls have it as not set.

Comment: Thanks so much. so, if i could find them can I fix them? the thing is when I see my landing pages without those custom dimensions, it shows 100% of sessions. but when I add those custom dimensions to the landing pages the session will drop. I will edit my question to show you what I mean (I will add some photos). I would appreciate it if you can have a look

Comment: once you find them, you'll see if you wanna fix them. Likely not. Or maybe it's indeed some kind of a front-end issue that you could fix. Anyhow, having default values will help a lot with debugging and further breaking down, so start from there and see if it helps.